# I uninstalled an app. How do I get it back?

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find out which apps I have already downloaded on my iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/how-can-i-find-out-which-apps-i-have-already-downloaded-on-my-iphone)

The [knowledge base](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1702) mentions that you get to reinstall the app for free... *once you find it again on the store*, which is no easy task. There are dozens of apps, all alike the one that was installed.

Is there a way to have a list of apps you have bought? At what point of the purchasing process does this dialog appear? Does a price tag appear for already purchased items? If so, does this message appear after you single tap on the price tag, or do you need to risk a double tap?

[image: link text]

Answer (score 6):

On **iTunes**, under **iTunes Store** > **Account** > **Purchase History**, you've got a list of all your iTunes Store purchases.

If you already bought an app, it still appears with the price on the Store. Last time I checked, I had to risk re-buying to see it was free since I already bought it.

Hope that helps!

[image: quick links itunes store]

[image]